# Disable image resize

Tags: image, options

Below is a screenshot of mathematica help :

[image]

As you see, if I click the image, orange colored frame appears, and we can control its size.

Can we make it impossible to resize an image ?

Probably by setting some option for the image, for example, `ImageSizeControl->Disable`.

Of course we should be able to copy/paste the image like other common images, but it should keep the original size after pasting.

I am concerned with precise arrangement of letters and images. In some process, kindness of the mathematica (automatic resizing, resize frame,...) makes it harder.

Comment: It's just a display thing. You're not resizing the actual data. If you drag the corner far enough, you'll start seeing each pixel as a large square.

Comment: Try `Deploy @ ...`.

Comment: I do `Image[image, Magnification -> 3/4]` to display images with the correct pixel size, but I'm not sure if its OS or hardware dependent

Comment: @Coolwater Have you seem [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468048)? :)

Comment: @ Kuba ♦, What a hidden command Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic resizing behavior you wish to disable is controlled by the option `ImageSizeMultipliers`. According to the [Documentaion page for `ImageSizeMultipliers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html) (under the "Properties & Relations" section):

> An explicit value of `ImageSize` always overrides a multiplier

Hence you just need to specify an explicit `ImageSize` for `Image`:

```
Image[#, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@#] &@Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]
{%}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, but the images are still resizable.

Comment: Yes... some minutes ago I posted an answer using `Deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

According to Kuba♦'s comment :

Below video shows all.
**Left mouse click to deployed imag**e has no effect in any sense.
**Right mouse click to deployed image** shows popup but without resizing frame.

[image]

P.S. To copy deployed image, you should drag the whole region of the image and (it seems easy to drag from right to left direction) right click, then choose copy in the popup. Just right clicking to the image does not show active(=not grayed out) copy menu. The copyed+pasted image is also deployed.
***It is unfortunate that copying deployed image is not very easy.*** See below video.

[image]

Comment: `Deploy` prevents manual resizing by the mouse, but not automatic resizing inside of `List`-like constructs, which is controlled by `ImageSizeMultipliers`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to copy deployed image ?

Comment: Probably not, because `Deploy` makes its contents non-selectable by mouse click. You can use the arrow keys on your keyboard with the Shift key pressed to select such an object for sure.

Comment: Thank you! Shift + arrow